# displaying table in html using 'for' loop from render_template()

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

Using Python Flask app to render a html table with 'for' loop implementation. But the data doesn't render giving a blank `<tr><tr>`.

I am converting a dataframe to html by passing a `dff.to_html()` from render_template and retrieving the table in html in a 'for' loop to display.

Python code:

```
return render_template('index.html', table = dff.head(50).to_html())
```

html code:

```
         <table>
            <tbody>

            {% for row in table %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.link_to_detail}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.link}}</td>
                    <td><input name ="get poster"  type="submit" value={{row['id']}}></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Actual result is

```
<tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input name="get poster" type="submit" value=""></td>
</tr>
```

Expected result :

```
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>link_to_detail</td>
      <td>link</td>
      <td><input name="get poster" type="submit" value=""></td>
    </tr>
```

'''

Comment: `table` is a string with HTML so you can use `{{ table }}` to put it in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `dff.head().to_html()` which returns an HTML table as a string, but instead `dff[:50].values` (gives you 2d-array of all columns of the first 50 rows) and then `row.0` and `row.1` to get the values of the first two columns on each row.

Answer (score 2):

`dff.head(50).to_html()` returns an html table, not a python object.

This html table is actually a string, and you are iterating over characters (`row`), which do not have any attributes called `name`, `link` or `link_to_detail`...

> *I'll be able to complete this answer if you post a sample of your `dff` dataframe.*

Answer (score 0):

I have never work python but idea is you need to send variables to view.

```
return render_template('index.html', table = dff.head(50).to_html(),  name='name' ,row.link_to_detail= 'row.link_to_detail' , link ='link')
```

it can be like this